# Function related to partition that includes all elements?

Tags: clojure

This behavior of Clojure's `partition` function is not what I need:

```
user=> (partition 3 (range 3))
((0 1 2))
user=> (partition 3 (range 4))
((0 1 2))
user=> (partition 3 (range 5))
((0 1 2))
user=> (partition 3 (range 6))
((0 1 2) (3 4 5))
```

I need the 'leftover' portions of the collection to be included, e.g.:

```
user=> (partition* 3 (range 4))
((0 1 2) (3))
user=> (partition* 3 (range 5))
((0 1 2) (3 4))
```

Is there a standard library function that does what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for `partition-all`. Just replace it in your example:

```
user> (partition-all 3 (range 4))
((0 1 2) (3))
user> (partition-all 3 (range 5)) 
((0 1 2) (3 4))
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a `pad` argument in the 4-arity version of `partition`:

```
user=> (partition 3 3 [] (range 4))
((0 1 2) (3))

user=> (partition 3 3 [] (range 5))
((0 1 2) (3 4))
```

The docstring:

```
user=> (doc partition)
-------------------------
clojure.core/partition
([n coll] [n step coll] [n step pad coll])
  Returns a lazy sequence of lists of n items each, at offsets step
  apart. If step is not supplied, defaults to n, i.e. the partitions
  do not overlap. If a pad collection is supplied, use its elements as
  necessary to complete last partition upto n items. In case there are
  not enough padding elements, return a partition with less than n items.
```